# How can I group/reuse named scopes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I group named scopes? For example, I have two models, User and Activity. A user can have many activities.

Activity has two named scopes:

```
Activity.ordered_by_created_at
Activity.top_20
```

I want to create a new named scope `Activity.recent` such that

```
Activity.recent == Activity.ordered_by_created_at.top_20
```

That way, I can call recent on `user.activities`.

```
user.activities.recent
```

Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call user.activities, assuming you have a has_many :activities relationship in your user.rb file, ActiveRecord will return an array of all the users activities.

Might want to consider changing the approach a la Activtiy.recent.user(UID) and just write a named_scope in your activity.rb file that finds associated users with the activity.

Comment: Hmmm... Yeah, Activity.find_by_user_id(user.id).recent is probably the way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.recent
    ordered_by_created_at.top_20
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did. But it doesn't work for `user.activities.recent`